# How to print some information from AdhocHost?

Tags: omnet++, inet

Recently, I started making a wireless network on OMNeT++, by following [this tutorial](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/wireless/power/doc/index.html). The network is composed of multiple `AdhocHost` that communicate with each other. Here's the `NED` file :

```
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.physicallayer.wireless.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.canvas.integrated.IntegratedCanvasVisualizer;

network WirelessNetwork
{
    parameters:
        
    submodules:
        visualizer: IntegratedCanvasVisualizer {@display("p=100,100");}
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {@display("p=100,200");}
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {@display("p=100,300");}
        host[3]: AdhocHost {@display("p=150,300");}
}
```

I want to print some information, using the `finish()` function. I've tried something like this :

```
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;


class host: public cSimpleModule
{
protected :
    void finish() override;
};

Define_Module(host);

void host::finish()
{
    EV << "hello world !\n";
}
```

But when I launch the simulation, nothing happens and no errors occur. I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I see several misunderstandings in your question.

1. In order to create own simple module one has to define C++ class as well as NED declaration - take a look at [Defining Simple Module Types](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:defining-simple-modules). You didn't declare a simple module in NED.
2. After creating simple module in C++/NED it may be used somewhere in the simulation network by declaring in a NED file something like `mod1: MyModule;` where `MyModule` is declared simple module. Take a look at [TicToc Tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part1/#13-adding-the-ned-file).
3. `AdhocHost` is [compound module](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:compound-modules) so it contains simple modules.  See: `src/inet/node/inet/AdhocHost.ned`:

   ```
   module AdhocHost extends WirelessHost
   {
      parameters:
      @display("i=device/cellphone");
      wlan[*].mgmt.typename = default("Ieee80211MgmtAdhoc");
      wlan[*].agent.typename = default("");
      forwarding = default(true);
   }
   ```

   It means that the behavior of `AdhocHost` is described in many simple modules:

[image]

You have to decide from which module you intend to print some information.

Comment: So I have to modify some simple `AdhocHost` modules directly to do what I want ? In my case I need to print the energy consumption of the `AdhocHost` nodes, so I have to modify the `finish()` function of the `NodeBase` module ?

Comment: 1. `NodeBase` is compound module, not a simple module. So it does not have own C++ class nor own `finish()`.   2. What module has knowledge about the energy consumption you are interested in?

Comment: I'm interested in the `energyStorage (SimpleEpEnergyStorage)` and `energyManagement (SimpleEpEnergyManagement)` modules. They don't appear on your image because I've added them to the `ini` fine.

Comment: It means that you have added `energyStorage` module to the `AdhocHost` and you want to print some information from `energyStorage`, doesn't it? To do it just add `EV << "something"` in the code of `energyStorage`. Could you clarify your problem as well as could you provide [mcve]?

Comment: Adding `EV << "something"` to the code of `energyStorage` seems to be a solution to my problem but something bothers me, am I forced to modify the source code ? From a programming point of view, it seems a bit inappropriate.

Comment: Could you write what information you need print from `SimpleEpEnergyStorage`?